# How to mock a new function/object creation call in javascript using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to mock an object instantiation call within another function in Javascript using Jasmine JS along with Karma. The code snippet looks like this:

```
ClassA = function(){
    var objB = new ClassB(); // How to fake this call?

    function method(){
        // Want to test this method
    }
}

ClassB = function(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Sinon.js:
http://sinonjs.org/

We sinon you can declare spies and stubs, allowing you to check if a function (spy) was called or to inject functions returning certain values (stubs).

Also if you want to mock the whole class B I would recommend you to inject it in the class constructor (dependency injection) this way you can inject your mock during test.